# Creating and initialize a class inside another class (nested) C#

Tags: c#, class, nested

I'm very new in C# and i need some help to use nested classes on my "Hello World" proyect.

I'm trying to create a class callable using **class1.subclass1.function(args...)** (to create groups of related functions), and I've done something that is working but I think that is not the best way to do it.

My code needs to share a variable between principal class and nested classes (a db handle), and I'm using and argument at class initialization to do it.

```
namespace SameAsPrincipal
{
    public class class1
    {
        public SQLiteConnection handle = null;
        public _subclass1 subclass = null;

        public class1(string db_file)
        {
            handle = new SQLiteConnection(db_file);
            subclass1 = new _subclass1(handle);
        }

        public _subclass1
        {
            private SQLiteConnection handle = null;

            public _subclass1(SQLiteConnection handle)
            {
                this.handle = handle;
            }

            public void function(args...)
            {
                //Do something here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Someone knows a better way to create nested classes and share objects between main and nested?

Thanks!!

Comment: To get the syntax you desire, subclass1 and its methods will need to be static, but, I'm uncertain if you'd be able to access class1's properties, methods, etc, without needing to pass them in as parameters to subclass1's methods.

Comment: Thanks to all help and suggestions. Finally i've created a new namespace called db_manage and inside that namespace i've created the classes with her methods. Now is like i want: db_manage.class.method();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context as to what the specific application is, it's hard to tell if it's appropriate or not.  I agree with the previous answer that it is generally more correct to have separate classes.  Your class B can still take a DB handle reference in its constructor, and class A can even pass it to it.  That's fine.  It's not so much that they are sharing the variable as that they both have a reference to the same DB handle.

The only time I've ever seen sub/inner classes and not thought it was weird was for like simple data objects that are only ever used within the parent class (although they may be referenced outside).  For example, if I made a linked list class, I may choose to have the node class be an inner class.  For just grouping functionality, regular classes should do that.

Namespaces can also be used for further grouping.  For example, maybe all my text operations are in a "MyApp.Text" namespace, but then they are further grouped into classes like "NumberUtils", "NameUtils", and "ZipUtils".

Comment: Thanks and I'm Sorry, english is not my main language and sometimes I have difficulties to explain what I want. The app is to manage an SQLite db with different tables, then I want to group all clases on a main class with the DB inicialization, create a subclass for every table and some functions on every subclass. For example: db.music.add(title, artist...), db.music.get(ID), db.film.add(title, director...). "db" is the main class that contains the database handle, music and film are the nested classes that needs to access to main class db hande, and add/get are functions inside Subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

I am unclear as to why you would want to use a nested class in this instance.  The way you have it written, the subclass is all you need.  If you want multiple methods (or as you called them "functions") just add your methods.

Is there some hidden reason you would want to use nested classes here?  As a general rule, nested classes are rarely needed.

```
namespace SameAsPrincipal
{
  public class Class1
  {
    private SQLiteConnection handle;

    public Class1(string db_file)
    {
      handle = new SQLiteConnection(db_file);
    }

    public int AddRecord(Record record)
    {
      // use handle to add record and get record Id
      return record.Id;
    }

    public void DeleteRecord(int id)
    {
      // Use handle to delete record
    }
  }
}
```

When you instantiate the object you will pass in your db_file and the connection object will be created.  Then every method could use that connection object when they are called.  However it is usually a better idea to create the connection for each method when it is called and disposing of the connection as soon as you the operation is completed.  This, of course, depends on your operations and if they are transnational.  For the most part using a "using" block to instantiate your connection is a good way to use connection objects.  The sooner you release the connection the sooner the machine will reuse that connection, you can lookup connection pooling to learn more.

Here is an example method that is using the "using" to add a person using a stored procedure:

```
public int AddPerson(Person person)
{
  using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbFile))
  {
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("spAddPerson",connection))
    {
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      var idParameter = new SQLiteParameter("@Id", DbType.Int32);
      idParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      command.Parameters.Add(idParameter);

      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", person.FirstName);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LirstName", person.LastName);

      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }

  return person.Id;
}
```

**edit:** In regard to your comment below

A few things:

1. Use namespaces not a parent class to group classes.
2. Instead of sub-classes you should just add all the database methods to the database class and create classes to model your objects.
3. Each class should be in it's own file
4. The namespace parts are ..[]*  I.E. Music class has the namespace YourApplication.YourProject.Models - inside the YourProject project, within a first level folder named Music you will find a file named Music.cs and with in that file you will find your music class.  This is not a requirement, the compiler does not care about structure like that.  It will only make your life easier when you start to get more code developed.

Here is an example of the code structure I am speaking of (remember each of these sections is it's own file)

Create a folder at the root of your project called Models. In this Models folder create a file named Music.cs

```
namespace YourApplication.YourProject.Models
{
  public class Music
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In this same (Models) folder create a file called Film.cs

```
namespace YourApplication.YourProject.Models
{
  public class Film
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string[] Actors { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Now back at the project root (no longer in Models folder) create a new folder called Persistence.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using YourApplication.YourProject.Models;

namespace YourApplication.YourProject.Persistence
{
  public static class DatabaseActions
  {
    public static string dbFile;

    public static Music[] ListMusic()
    {
      var musicList = new List<Music>();

      // database call to get all music
      using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbFile))
      {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("spGetMusic", connection))
        {
          var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

          // The try finally blocks are not strictly needed as these will are suppose to be called upon disposal
          try
          {
            // loop through records creating music objects
            while (reader.Read())
            {
              var music = new Music();
              music.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
              music.Title = reader.GetString(1);
              musicList.Add(music);
            }
          }
          finally
          {
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
          }
        }
      }
      return musicList.ToArray();
    }

    public static int SaveMusic(Music music)
    {
      if (music.Id == 0)
      {
        // database stuff - getting the newly created database id  
      }
      else
      {
        // database calls to update record
      }

      return music.Id;
    }

    public static int SaveFilm(Film film)
    {
      if (film.Id == 0)
      {
        // database stuff - getting the newly created database id  
      }
      else
      {
        // database calls to update record
      }

      return film.Id;
    }


    public static Music GetMusic(int id)
    {
      var music = new Music();

      // database call and setting of values on music

      return music;
    }


    public static Film GetFilm(int id)
    {
      var film = new Film();

      // database call and setting of values on music

      return film;
    }

  }
}
```

Now finally create a file on the root called WorkHarness.cs

```
using System;
using YourApplication.YourProject.Persistence;


namespace YourApplication.YourProject
{
  public class WorkHarness
  {

    public void Initialize()
    {
      DatabaseActions.dbFile = "your db file";
    }

    public void ShowMusicList()
    {
      // list the id and title so user can select by Id
      foreach (var music in DatabaseActions.ListMusic())
      {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}{1}",music.Id,music.Title);
      }
    }

    public void DisplayMusicItem(int id)
    {
      var music = DatabaseActions.GetMusic(id);

      Console.WriteLine("Title: " + music.Title);
      Console.WriteLine("Length: " + music.Length);
      Console.WriteLine("Artist: " + music.Artist);
      Console.WriteLine("Album: " + music.Album);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!! I've to think about this a little more, The only reason to use nested classes is to create a tree of methods grouped by kind. For example A class dbase that contains two subclasses called music and film, and every subclass with two methods called add and get. To add music i want to call it with dbase.music.add(): http://s32.postimg.org/4wykyncp1/example.png

Comment: I added some code to the bottom that should match your scenario a bit better.  Hopefully this puts you down a better path :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting the objects, create two classes (at the same scope) and have one use the other, such as this:

```
public class ClassA
{
  public ClassB InstanceOfClassB { get; set; }

  public ClassA()
  {
    InstanceOfClassB = new ClassB();
  }
  //More code here
}

public class ClassB
{
  //Code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!. I need to keep using arguments to pass object between both classes?

Comment: @DanielCarrascoMarín Not sure if I understand the question, but... An **instance** of an non-primitive object when handed around is handed around **by reference**, meaning if an instance of ClassA and an instance ClassC get the same **instance** of ClassB, changing a property on that **instance** of ClassB will be visible by both your instances of ClassA and ClassC. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @DanielCarrascoMarín If that doesn't answer your question (or you don't understand my answer) I'd be more than happy to help you through understanding Object Oriented design (which is what we're dealing with). I wish SO had a good one-on-one chat feature/PM, on that note...

Comment: Thanks, I've to do some test to see if I've understood your answer. I'm new on object programing and there are a lot of things that I don't know.

Anyway i'll ask: my above question is about if i can access from ClassB to an object or variable created on ClassA. For example, i create a variable int number = 20 on ClassA and i want to access to that variable from ClassB. I can do it or i've to use a parameter as i did on the example of the main post?

Comment: @DanielCarrascoMarín So you could set that up (by ClassA handing a reference to itself to ClassB) but that two-way awareness is almost always frowned upon, and is considered an "anti-pattern;" things like that will typically make your code harder to debug, test, expand, and maintain. **Generally** you want your classes as unaware of one another as is possible; this concept is called "decoupling." As you progress in C# you'll find more and more features that will let you do this. If you have any questions about what I just said, just ask and I'll dive into greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

Using Nested classes in a HelloWorld project? Not a good sign!!

I would suggest not to use nested types ***Unless*** you know what you're doing and you have very good explanation to give when asked. Also a note of advice by .NET Framework Guidelines which explicitly recommend against creating `public` nested classes.

For data sharing in Object oriented programming we have `inheritance` feature which is the best way to share data/members access across classes based on relationship/association.

> to create groups of related functions

As @Nex Terren suggested (with a little modification), you can do something like this, here your Principle class will work as Factory and different classes will provide Aggregation of related functions by their instance

```
public class PrincipleClass
{
  public ClassB InstanceOfClassB { get; private set; }
  public ClassA InstanceOfClassA { get; private set; }

  public PrincipleClass(string db_file)
  {
    InstanceOfClassA = new ClassA(new SQLiteConnection(db_file));
    InstanceOfClassB = new ClassB();
  }
  //More code here
}

public class ClassA
{
  public ClassA(SQLiteConnection handle)
  {
     // your code here
  }
  public void FunctionOfA1() { }
  public void FunctionOfA2() { }
}

public class ClassB
{
  public void FunctionOfB1() { }
  public void FunctionOfB2() { }
}
```

Now you'll have your group of function together like

`new PrincipleClass.InstanceOfClassA.FunctionOfA1();`
`new PrincipleClass.InstanceOfClassB.FunctionOfB1();`

Note - This may also not be a best solution but this is way better than using Nested types.

Comment: Thanks!!, I'll try to take a look to inheritance. I need some time to digest the Microsoft info about that ;)

Comment: Its not specific to Microsoft but ist more of learning object oriented approach to design a solution. Cheers!!